# fscanf, corrupted float variable after loading

Tags: c++, floating-point, scanf

I'm writing a simple Wavefront format loader for my DirectX project in C++. The thing is I've encountered a small yet difficult problem. fscanf corrupts loaded data to variable. When loading [THIS](http://pastebin.com/XY3GuHKE) file, the output variable vt.y gets corrupted at line 13, which is as follows:

```
vt 0.500000 0.000087
```

And the code that brings me so much trouble is the one below. I've tried two solution, first is reading the line and then trying to parse it using sscanf, but it fails, although the input fgets grabs is completely fine. The second one uses fscanf, but also fails.

```
// earlier declarations:
float d1 = 0.0f, d2 = 0.0f;

...

else if ( strcmp ( "vt", (const char*)line ) == 0 )
{
    char temp[256];
    XMFLOAT2 vt;
    //the 1st method: DON'T USE THEM BOTH TOGETHER, ONE OF THEM MUST CE COMMENTED OUT
    fgets ( temp, sizeof( temp ), f ); // Result is correct: " 0.500000 0.000087\n"
    sscanf ( temp, "%f %f", &d1, &d2 ); // d1 = 0.500000, d2 = 8.70000003e-005

    //the 2nd method: DON'T USE THEM BOTH TOGETHER, ONE OF THEM MUST CE COMMENTED OUT
    fscanf_s ( f, "%f %f", &vt.x, &vt.y ); // vt.x = 0.500000, vt.y = 8.70000003e-005
    tex.push_back ( vt );
}
```

The code is compiles with flag:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE
```

I will appreciate your help.

Comment: I don't see any problem with either method - what is it that you're not happy with exactly ?

Comment: Is it the fact that 0.000087 becomes 0.0000870000003 that's bothering you?

Comment: Are you referring to the scientific notation, `8.70000003e-05`? That's equivalent to `0.0000870000003`. And the little bit at the end is due to rounding errors in floating point. So it really is, basically, `0.000087`. You can control what they look like when you print them out using an appropriate format string.

Comment: Oh, thank you, @mbratch. So as it turns out, I'm quite blind and additionally forgot some quite basic maths.

Comment: 8.70000003e-05 is the same as 0.000087, when using scientific notation.